# How to retrieve records using textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to use the wildcard query to display rows in a gridview but it is not up to the mark...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Alphabates where Word 
                     like'"+TextBox1.Text+"'", new SqlConnection("data source=
                     USER\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=vicky;integrated 
                     security=true"));

    try
    {
        com.Connection.Open();
        GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        com.Connection.Close();
        com.Connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: @pascal i want if i am enter ab so it should display all the records from my Alphabates data base plzz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Change your query to add % around the text box value

wildcard  search requires a % sign to get the desired result, other wise it would be same as using an equal to(=) sign

```
"select * from Alphabates where Word like %'"+TextBox1.Text+"%'"
```

As per your comment if you want rows starting with given word then:

```
"select * from Alphabates where Word like '"+TextBox1.Text+"%'"
```

Ex:

```
select * from Alphabates where Word like 'Some value'
```

is same as

```
select * from Alphabates where Word ='Some value'
```

so you should change it to

```
select * from Alphabates where Word like '%Some value%'
```

Comment: Please check the quotes.. I have updated my answer.. plz check now

Comment: i want if am enter Word in textbox like 'ab' so it should display all the words that starts like 'aback','abase','abort'...........

Comment: Select * from Alphabates where Word like '%"textbox1.text"%' it is another query ...............

Comment: Buddy I have already Voted your answer as useful ......................... Thanxxx Againnnnn.............

Answer (score 0):

Please be wary of sql injection.

You should add % around the text value, then use parametized sql to run it, not composing it using string.   You'll be opened to all sorts of clever sql.

Take a look at the example here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html